# Taylor Theorem inequality

Tags: calculus, derivatives, taylor-expansion

Prove that for all $f\in C^2([0,1])$ with $f(0)=f(1)=0$ and $|f''(x)| \le 1$ $$|f(x)| \le \frac{1}{2}x(1-x)$$  $\forall  x \in [0,1]$.

Comment: If your function is only continuous, how do you know for sure that it has a second derivative?

Comment: Mistake in the post, sorry! Just corrected…

Comment: You have only accepted an answer in 2/20 questions asked. You should remember to [accept](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/3287/147873) the answer you though was most useful to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some $\xi_k\in[0,1]$,
$$
f(1)=f(0)+f'(0)+\frac12f''(\xi_1)
\quad\text{and}\quad
f(0)=f(1)-f'(1)+\frac12f''(\xi_2)
$$
implies
$$
|f'(0)|\le\frac12
\quad\text{and}\quad
|f'(1)|\le\frac12
$$
Let $g(x)=f(x)-\frac12x(1-x)$ and $h(x)=f(x)+\frac12x(1-x)$.

$g(0)=0$, $g'(0)\le0$, and $g''(x)\le0$; therefore, $g(x)\le0$.

$h(0)=0$, $h'(0)\ge0$, and $h''(x)\ge0$; therefore, $h(x)\ge0$.

Thus,
$$
\overbrace{-\frac12x(1-x)\le}^{h(x)\ge0}f(x)\overbrace{\le\frac12x(1-x)}^{g(x)\le0}
$$

Comment: Can you explain why $g(0)=0, g′(0)≤0$, and $g″(x)≤0$; therefore, $g(x)≤0$?

Comment: @TheMaker94: Mean Value Theorem on $[0,1]$. Since $g'(0)\le0$ and $g''(x)\le0$, we have $g'(x)\le0$. Since $g(0)=0$ and $g'(x)\le0$, $g(x)\le0$.

Comment: Perfect, clear thanks!

Answer (score 3):

We have, $\displaystyle (1-x)\int_0^x tf''(t)\,dt -x \int_x^1 (t-1)f''(t)\,dt = -f(x)$, for $x \in [0,1]$ (just apply integration by parts on LHS to ease the simplification).

Since, $t\ge 0$ for $t\in [0,1]$ and $(t-1) \le 0$ for $t \in [0,1]$, taking modulus on both sides,

$|f(x)| = \displaystyle \left|(1-x)\int_0^x tf''(t)\,dt -x \int_x^1 (t-1)f''(t)\,dt\right|$

$\le \displaystyle \left|(1-x)\int_0^x tf''(t)\,dt\right| + \left|-x \int_x^1 (t-1)f''(t)\,dt\right|$

$\le \displaystyle \sup\limits_{t\in[0,1]}|f''(t)|. \bigg( (1-x)\int_0^x t\,dt -x \int_x^1 (t-1)\,dt \bigg)$

$= \dfrac{x(1-x)}{2}.\sup\limits_{t\in[0,1]}|f''(t)| \le \dfrac{x(1-x)}{2}$.

*Aliter:* Define $g(t)=f(t)-\dfrac{t(t-1)}{x(x-1)}f(x)$, on $[0,1]$.

Then, $g(0)=g(x)=g(1)=0$.

Applying Rolle's Theorem twice on $(0,1)$, $\exists \alpha \in (0,1)$ such that $g''(\alpha)=0$.

That is $g''(\alpha) = f''(\alpha) - \dfrac{2}{x(x-1)}f(x)=0$

or, $|f(x)|=\dfrac{x(1-x)}{2}|f''(\alpha)| \le \dfrac{x(1-x)}{2}$.

Comment: How do you pull $\sup|f''(t)|$ out of the integrals while maintaining the subtraction between the integrals? Suppose $f''(t)=1$ on $[0,x]$ and $f''(t)=-1$ on $[x,1]$ (or a continuous function very close to that).

Comment: I think if you add the absolute values of the integrals you get what you want. That is, $$\frac12x^2(1-x)+\frac12x(1-x)^2=\frac12x(1-x)$$

Comment: @robjohn fixed typo and added a line .. thanks for pointing it out :)

Comment: Nice way the second one! I thought that it would be good to do with Taylor Theorem (therefore the title) but I found no way.

Answer (score 2):

> We want to prove that for each $x$:$$
> \exists c\ \ f(x) =\frac 12 f''(c) x(1-x)
> $$

We want to find such a $c$ via the Rolle theorem (or via the mean value theorem, but we can always go back to the Rolle version).

We can already apply the Rolle theorem,  which gives an annulation for $f'$.

Let us modify $f$ to go to $0$ once more: assuming $0<x<1$,

$$
g(u) := f(u) + A_xu(1-u)\\
g(x) = 0\Leftarrow A_x = - \frac{f(x)}{x(1-x)}
$$

Now $g(1)=g(x) = g(0)$ hence, applying several times
the Rolle theorem:

$$
\exists c \ \ 0=g''(c) = f''(c)  - \frac{f(x)}{x(1-x)}(-2)\\
f(x) = -\frac 12 x(1-x)f''(c)
$$

NB: the error in the sign does not change the final inequality.

Comment: clever idea (+1)